# change global variable through dictionary (python)

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

Beginner question here. I'm trying to modify a global variable by a function using dictionary. Sample code here:

```
count = 0
sample = {'a' : [False, count, 20], 'b' : [False, count, 60]}

d = raw_input('give dict key: ')
    for each in sample:
        if each == d:
            sample[each][0] = True
        sample[each][1] += sample[each][2]

print('count ' + str(count))
print(sample) 
print('count ' + str(count))
```

The result is (no surprise):

```
give dict key: b
count 0
{'a': [False, 0, 20], 'b': [True, 60, 60]}
count 0
```

I understand the result, but I'd like to know if there's any way to access and change the global variable, so that `count` in last line would give `60` not `0`. (Preferably with simple methods, OOP is out of my reach at the moment).

### #

EDIT:
Thank you for the answers! I wasn't precise enough and proposed solutions will not work in my case. The statement above is a part of a bigger function and there's more variables also, let's try to redefine it:

```
countOne = 0
countTwo = 0

sample = {'a' : [False, countOne, 20, 'mouse'], 'b' : [False, countTwo, 60, 'cat']}



def someFunction():
    global countOne, countTwo
    while something:
        if somethingElse:
            if anotherThing:
                d = raw_input('give dict key: ')
                for each in sample:
                    if each == d:
                        sample[each][0] = True
                        sample[each][1] += sample[each][2]

print('count ' + str(count))
print(sample) 
print('count ' + str(count))
```

I'm sorry for confusion, haven't thought that shortening it, would allow other methods to be applicable.

For the first answer, it wouldn't work, because in my dictionary I have quite a lot of global variables (more than those two above) and according to the raw_input the specific variable should be accessed and modified.

For the second answer, it wouldn't work as it's not local anymore.

Comment: All the variables in your code are global, since there's no function, so there is no problem changing any of them. Just put an assignment to `count` wherever you want it.

Comment: The indentation of your code looks odd.  I think the "for each in sample" line should not be indented.  Right?  Also, your question mentions a function, but the code does not define a function?

Comment: At the end of your code, should `sample['a'][1]` also be 60?

Comment: I recommand studying https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html and https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html. It's about python dictionary data structure, mutable and immutable data types, `globals()` and `locals()` functions.

Comment: Why do you need `sample['a'][1]` to be an alias to a global variable in the first place? You'd be better off rethinking your design rather than messing with apparently unnecessary global variables.

Comment: @chepner, Yes, I believe it has to be global variable. It's accessed and modified in two separate functions, both working non-stop (while True:), one with use of thread.

Comment: But why have `countOne` when you already have `sample['a'][1]`? You're duplicating data for no good reason, and the result is your problem of keeping them in sync. Plus, anytime you start having multiple functions that need to share state, it's a good sign those functions should be methods of a class that encapsulates the state.

Comment: @chepner, At a moment I cannot use classes (but I intend to rewrite the program with the use of it in some time). All just for sake of exercise and hopefully it will give me more practical idea of use of classes. `countOne` is accessed by another function, increasing the value by 1 every second. After reaching a certain value I use dictionary to modify the increase of the `countOne` (and others) to increase it not by 1 each second, but let's say 5 each second. Same with other variables. Anyway, problem is solved. Thank you for your input in discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, an assumption. I'm assuming that you don't know ahead of time which variable you're going to be modifying.

If that's accurate, the following will do what you want:

```
count = 0
sample = {'a' : [False, 'count', 20], 'b' : [False, 'count', 60]}

d = input('give dict key: ')
print('count ' + str(count))
for each in sample:
    if each == d:
        sample[each][0] = True
        locals()[sample[each][1]] += sample[each][2]


print(sample) 
print('count ' + str(count))
```

Yields:

```
give dict key: b
count 0
{'a': [False, 'count', 20], 'b': [True, 'count', 60]}
count 60
```

Note that I changed the second entry in each list to a string, so it's not interpreted at the point of the dictionary creation.

locals() will return the list of the local symbol table. Note that in this context, count is a local variable, not a global variable. You're just at the highest scope so it's a distinction without a difference. Once you have the symbol table you can assign to it like any list.

Comment: If that assumption is inaccurate, go with @ppflrs answer, it's much simpler.

Comment: I used your solution, just changed "locals()" with "globals()" as the modification was taking place inside the function (which I haven't stated in original question). Thank you!